# Angular7, Select directive not selecting option when options are loaded asynchronously

Tags: angular, asynchronous, select

I have a select whose options are generated with an http request.
When I get the answer and I set the options tag with `*ngFor` the first result appears as selected in the form, however looking at the `ngModel` they have no value selected

html

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filter.account">
  <option *ngFor="let account of accounts">{{account.name}}</option>
</select>
```

ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filter = new AccountsCallLogFilter();
    this._acs.accounts().subscribe(
      val => {
        this.accounts = val;
        // this.filter.account = this.accounts[0].name; // <-- that works
      }
    );
  }
```

this.filter is a class of this type

```
export class AccountsCallLogFilter {
    public "account": string
    public "dateFrom": string
    public "dateTo": string
}
```

response example

```
[{ "accountId": "123456", "name": "Account1", "count": 2990 },
 { "accountId": "654321", "name": "Account2", "count": 5789 }]
```

I would like that when receiving the answer the ngModel will be updated without having to do something like

```
this._acs.accounts().subscribe(
      val => {
        this.accounts = val;
        this.filter.account = this.accounts[0].name;
  }
);
```

when i change manually the option, value updates correctly, the problem is only at load

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided value for options so select has no clue how to bind it. Try this:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filter.account">
  <option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [value]="account.accountId">{{account.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: dont works, when i change manually the option, value updates correctly, the problem is only at load;

Comment: try changing [(ngModel)]="filter.account" to [(ngModel)]="filter.account?.accountId"

Comment: @VugarAbdullayev, if you give to your options [value]=account.accountId you need make filter.account=this.accounts[0].accountId, if you give to your options [value]=account.name is correct filter.name=this.account[0].name

Comment: yes sorry I meant accounts[0].accountId  ;) Did it solve problem?

Comment: No, same problem @VugarAbdullayev